# I want to split string comma separated and join the values on another table in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle12c

Here is my Sql Code which is working fine but it is not working in Oracle.

Begin

```
Declare @ErrorCodes varchar(max)

if(isnull(@ErrorCodes,'') <> '')
    Begin
        WITH TempTable as
        (
        SELECT * FROM split(@ErrorCodes,',')
        )

        SELECT ErrorDescription 
        FROM TABLE E 
        INNER JOIN TempTable  
        ON ltrim(rtrim(TempTable.data)) = E.ErrorCode
    End
```

END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select ERRORDESCRIPTION INTO v_ErrorDesc from TABLE where Errorcode in  (
select cast(COLUMN_VALUE as Nvarchar2(4000)) ErrorCode from (
SELECT columnA    FROM TABLEA
  WHERE columnID = v_caseid )
  ,  xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(columnA, ',', '","') || '"')));

This worked for me I solved it by myself .. Thanks anyways!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is SQL Server's.

In Oracle you'd use hierarchical connect by for this sort of processing.

Say the CSV string is `1,2,3`, try this

```
select regexp_substr('1,2,3', '[^,]+', 1, level) as error_code
from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count('1,2,3', ',') + 1
```

Comment: this I have done but how to use this data to join on another query ? In SQL it can be done but how to use this on ORACLE

Comment: Just put it in a subquery or a CTE as you were doing

Comment: Done that by using subquery !! thanx